# How to use mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a database with collection name "sensors" and it looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a7e1f2cf1d7cba1fe3"), "type" : "thermometer", "value" : 23, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.698Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.698Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a7e1f2cf1d7cba1fe4"), "type" : "hygrometer", "value" : 74, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.739Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:31.739Z"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d4d27a8e1f2cf1d7cba1fe5"), "type" : "thermometer", "value" : 25, "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-08-09T07:58:32.551Z"), "__v" : 0 }
```

What I want to do is to query on the very last two documents, thermometer and hygrometer then check the value for each of the documents. Then based on the conditions I set using $match tag, I perform any operations I want.

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost', { useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err, client) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var db = client.db('mongodb');
    db.collection('sensors').aggregate(
     [
       { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
       { $limit: 1 },
       {
        $match: {"type": "hygrometer", "value": { "$gt": 60 } }
       }
     ]
   ).toArray(function(err, item) {
         if(err) console.log('error');
         if(item.length > 0) console.log('Dehumidifier ON');
         else console.log('Dehumidifier OFF');
});
```

This is the implementation for the very last data only (hygrometer) but how should I make it to check the last two documents then perform a separate operation for thermometer for example "AC ON/OFF"? I was thinking somehow make it check when item.type == "thermometer" perform something but that item.type syntax seems to not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below query:

```
db.aggtest.aggregate([
   { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
   { $limit: 2 },
   {$match: { $or: [ {"type": "hygrometer", "value": { "$gt": 60 }}, {"type": "thermometer"} ]}}
   ])
```